# Javascript assignment operator weird behaviour

Tags: javascript, variable-assignment, assignment-operator

I was working on one event widget and found strange behavior,it may be noob question.

Below is code block I was working on

```
var event={0:{competition:{like:false}}}
console.log(event[0].competition.like);   //returns false
var cmpt=event[0].competition;
cmpt.like=true;
console.log(event[0].competition.like) //returns true
```

Can you help me understanding, why value of **attribute [like] of competition inside event object** is getting updated.
and how can I prevent this and not updated event object?

I tried looking into google/so but those questions were addressing different problem.

Comment: you are just copying a reference, not the object.

Comment: It's because in javascript objects are pass by reference, to make it make it work the way you want you need to clone the competition object.

Comment: If it's not a string or a number then it's a reference (pointer). To copy an object (instead of pointing to it) do `Object.create(event[0].competition)`

Comment: @slebetman that will create new object with prototype set to `event[0].competition` and when you modify `like` it will modify `event[0].competition`

Comment: @jcubic the first part is true, but it would not modify ˋevent[0].competitionˋ, it would create a new property ˋlikeˋ on the newly created object.

Comment: @jcubic: No it will not: https://jsfiddle.net/yfyv74nm/

Comment: @jcubic: While the implementation details of `Object.create()` strictly inherits from the given object the semantics is exactly equivalent to deep cloning. Changing the parent object will not change the child and changing the child object will not change the parent. That is why `Object.create()` is considered the standard deep copy technique in modern js environments.

Comment: @slebetman look at this https://jsfiddle.net/yfyv74nm/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can you help me understanding, why value of attribute [like] of
>   competition inside event object is getting updated

You copied the reference of `event[0].competition` in `cmpt` by doing this assignment.

Now `cmpt` is pointing to the same object to which `event[0].competition` is pointing to. So, if you update the value it will basically make changes in the same object to which both variables are pointing to.

> how can I prevent this and not updated event object?

If you want to ensure that older values shouldn't get updated then you need to deep-clone the object while assigning

Replace

```
var cmpt=event[0].competition;
```

with

```
var cmpt=JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( event[0].competition ) );
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I used jQuery.clone to copy object in new variable.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning reference to

```
    event[0].competition
```

to variable `cmpt` and then modify it's value - whatever you will do with original instance will affect the `cmpt` variable also

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript objects are always passed by reference. This means that when you assign an object to another variable, it still points to the same object. If you want to have two separate objects, you have to clone it. You can do this for example using [`_.clone()` method from lodash library](https://lodash.com/docs#clone):

```
var cmpt = _.clone(event[0].competition);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have an object, and you 'copy' it like you did into a new object, and change the new object the old object is updated.

This is because you're not actually copying it, you just have another reference to that original object, so what ever you change on the 'copy' is reflected in the original...

Answer (score 1):

This is because in JavaScript, when you assign an object value to another variable, you are actually assigning a value to it (it doesn't get copied, like primitve values do).

so ˋcmptˋ and ˋevent[0].competitionˋ refer to the same object.

If you need to clone the object, and it only contains primitive values, arrays and simple objects (no functions), you could use ˋJSON.stringifyˋ and ˋJSON.parseˋ.

```
var event={0:{competition:{like:false}}}
console.log(event[0].competition.like);       //returns false
var cmpt=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(event[0].competition));
cmpt.like=true;
console.log(event[0].competition.like)
//returns false
```

Answer (score 1):

That why u are just "renaming" the event, you can do like this.

```
var event={0:{competition:{like:false}}}
console.log(event[0].competition.like);   //returns false
var cmpt = {};
cmpt.like = event[0].competition.like;
cmpt.like = true;
console.log(event[0].competition.like) //returns false
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
var event={0:{competition:{like:false}}}
console.log(event[0].competition.like);   //returns false
var cmpt=jQuery.extend({}, event[0].competition);
cmpt.like=true;
console.log(event[0].competition.like) //returns false (changed)
```

Answer (score 1):

> and how can I prevent this and not updated event object?

You can use [`Object.create()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) with first parameter set to `null`; iterate `event[0].competition` properties at `value` of property descriptors at second parameter to `Object.create()`, setting value of each property to `null`, return newly created object having properties of `event[0].competition` set to `null`.

```js
var event = {
  0: {
    competition: {
      like: false
    }
  }
}

console.log(event[0].competition.like); //returns false

var cmpt = Object.create(null, {
  competition: {
    value: (function(obj) {
      var _obj = {};
      for (var prop in obj) {
        _obj[prop] = null
      };
      return _obj
    }(event[0].competition)),
    writable: true,
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true
  }
});
cmpt.competition.like = true;
console.log(event[0].competition.like, cmpt.competition.like
           , event[0], cmpt) //`false, `true`
```